# Sending mail with C#

Tags: c#, email

I set up my hMailServer on my windows 2008 machine, and I'm trying to send emails.

When I do it with C#

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress(from, "John");
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = body;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.example.com");
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("john@example.com", "password");
client.Send(message);
```

But when I try to send emails with a windows live email client, it gives me an error

> The connection to the server has failed

All the settings are exactly the same. I tried several email clients, but it doesn't work. It never happened to me before. I just moved from one machine to another, and got this problem.

I can receive mail in the client though...

Comment: You also might want to try asking this on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Can you try the Windows Live client from the server?  Have you tried to telnet from your desktop to port 25?

Comment: Yes, it works on the server. Telnetin' right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to telnet to port 25, can it connect?

Open up command prompt:

> telnet mail.example.com 25

If it cannot connect (which is what I expect) then you have a problem that is not code related but firewall related.  (Or perhaps you're trying to connect to the wrong port if they're running SMTP on a non standard port)

Comment: Yeah, I was able to send it from server's client. I'm installing telnet right now...

Comment: You are right. Connect failed. But even after turning off my anti virus and firewall, it still can't connect.

Comment: @Alex: From here you should post on serverfault.com, but you can see that it's not code related though.